# Material UI theme not applying

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Have a strange issue with material UI. The custom theme is not applying, I've tried wrapping the theme provider as multiple different levels of the application to troubleshoot but it is not applying, this is affecting all components - buttons, appbar etc.

I've also noticed my alerts are missing a background colour.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { RecoilRoot } from "recoil";
import App from "./App";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { client as ApolloClient } from "./lib/apolloClient";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#0971f1",
    },
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={ApolloClient}>
      <RecoilRoot>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <App />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </RecoilRoot>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Alert Code

```
<Alert severity="error">
    <AlertTitle>Data retrieval error</AlertTitle>
    {error.message}
</Alert>
```

These are my packages and versions

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.3",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.8.0",
    ....
  }
```

App.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: could you post alert part of your code?

Comment: @Anthony220 have updated the question with Alert code, it feels like I'm missing part of a stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your custom color theme is override by `severity` to serve as the color.

Here is what's written in the doc:

> The color of the component. Unless provided, the value is taken from the severity prop.

You can add `color` as a prop as stated in the doc: https://mui.com/api/alert/

```
<Alert severity="error" color="primary">
    <AlertTitle>Data retrieval error</AlertTitle>
    {error.message}
</Alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like I fixed the issue, i was importing @material-ui/core instead of @mui/material.